# android OpenCv : how to use floodfill function to find connected components

Tags: java, android, opencv

i am using floodfill function to find the connected components in a image in opencv for android.

```
Vector<Vector<Point>> blobReturn = null;
Mat labelImag = new Mat(dilatedImag.rows(),dilatedImag.cols(),CvType.CV_32FC1);
dilatedImag.convertTo(labelImag ,CvType.CV_32FC1);
int val = 2;
Scalar labelCount = new Scalar(val);
Mat mask = new Mat(labelImag.rows()+2, labelImag.cols()+2, CvType.CV_8UC1, new Scalar(0));

        for(int i=0;i<labelImag.rows();i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<labelImag.cols();j++)
            {
                double checker = labelImag.get(i, j)[0];
                Rect rect = null ;

                if(checker == 1)
                {
                    Imgproc.floodFill(labelImag, mask, new Point(j,i), labelCount, rect, new Scalar(0), new Scalar(0), 8);

                Vector<Point> blob = null;
                for(int k=rect.y; k < (rect.y+rect.height); k++) 
                {
                    for(int l=rect.x; l < (rect.x+rect.width); l++) 
                    {
                        double chk = labelImag.get(k,l)[0];
                        if(new Scalar(chk) == labelCount) 
                        {
                            blob.add(new Point(k,l));
                        }                        
                    }
                }

                blobReturn.add(blob);
                val=val+1;
                 labelCount=new Scalar(val);
                }

            }

        }
```

above mentioned is my code. my question is in which parameter i am getting the result of floodfill to find the position of connected component. i am getting null in rect. i have googled the problem everywhere it is explained in C or C++ which passes the pointer of rect and gets the result in rect but in java ?????

Comment: floodfill does not *find* anything. it just fills the image, until it hits a border.

Comment: did you confuse it with [findContours()](http://docs.opencv.org/java/org/opencv/imgproc/Imgproc.html#findContours(org.opencv.core.Mat,%20java.util.List,%20org.opencv.core.Mat,%20int,%20int)) ?

Comment: Why did you use as a starting point this "new Point(j,i)"?So you calling FloodFill for each Pixel again